# TERM=fbterm causes box-drawing characters (by curses) get scrambled

Tags: environment-variables, framebuffer, ncurses

I'm writing TUI software on `fbterm` using `python-curses` library.

To get full color in `fbterm`, I read it's man page and concluded I need to change environmental variable `TERM` to `fbterm`.

> Man page: `By default, FbTerm sets environment variable "TERM" to value "linux", user need run "TERM=fbterm /path/to/program" to enable 256 color mode.`

When I set `TERM=fbterm`, and run my python program. String-texts are OK, but the box/rectangle drawing character (`-` `|` `┌` ...) gets scrambled to (`Ä` `³` `¿` etc).

```
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿
 ³Meas.³
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿ ³1-shot      ³³n-shot      ³
 ³Setup³ ³            ³³            ³
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ ³            ³³            ³
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿ ³            ³³            ³
 ³Data ³ ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿
 ³About³ ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ ³Target      ³³Weather     ³
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄ¿ ³            ³³            ³
 ³Sys. ³ ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
 ÀÄÄÄÄÄÙ
```

What am I doing wrong (missing)??

Yesterday I cross posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74707640/14696853), Then I realize this problem is more to do with `fbterm`'s environmental value. So I'm posting here. The original post contains my reasoning, what I did, how I conclude so on ... (in more details).

Comment: What's the output of `locale`, `locale charmap`, `infocmp -1 fbterm | grep acs` for you?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce it (box drawing not working) if I start `fbterm` in any locale whose charmap is neither ANSI_X3.4-1968 (ASCII as in the `C` locale) nor UTF-8. Check the output of `locale charmap` to see what charmap is used in your locale (possibly ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 in your case given your output) and `locale` to see the current locale configuration.

```
$ infocmp -1 fbterm | grep acs
        acsc=+\020\,\021-\030.^Y0\333`\004a\261f\370g\361h\260i\316j\331k\277l\332m\300n\305o~p\304q\304r\304s_t\303u\264v\301w\302x\263y\363z\362{\343|\330}\234~\376,
        rmacs=\E[10m,
        smacs=\E[11m,
```

You can see for `fbterm`, the box drawing characters are bytes with the 8<sup>th</sup> bit set so I suppose it conflicts with normal characters when using character sets such as ISO8859-1 somehow (for instance the horizontal line character, mapped to VT100 `p` above is `\304` which happens to be `Ä` in ISO8859-1 aka latin1).

The easy work around would be to use a UTF-8 locale if you have one available.

See `locale -a` for the list of locales available on your system and start `fbterm` as:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 fbterm
```

For instance to start `fbterm` in a US-English locale with UTF-8 as charset (assuming the `LC_ALL` and `LC_CTYPE` environment variables are not otherwise set). You may also want to run `stty iutf8` in that terminal as it seems fbterm doesn't do it by itself when started in a UTF-8 locale.

On Debian-based systems, you can run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as superuser to change the default system locale.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But (I'm sorry) I just can't comprehend what you replied. What does it mean to use "UTF-8 locale" in this context?

Comment: @GaridZ. see edit.